# How do I skew the lower section of a UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, calayer, quartz-2d

I would like to skew the lower portion of a UIImage like this:

[image]

What would the best approach be?

Comment: One suggestion I received was to break the image into two, skew one of them, and then recombine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. It divides the image in two and then shears the bottom one:

```
CGFloat foldHeightInPercent = 0.9f;
CGFloat totalHeight = 39;
CGRect topImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, totalHeight * foldHeightInPercent);

//top image
CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
CGRect topCropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width * scale, image.size.height * foldHeightInPercent * scale);
CGImageRef topImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, topCropRect);
UIImageView *topImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:topImageRect];
[topImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImageRef]];
CGImageRelease(topImageRef);    
[self.view addSubview:topImageView];

//bottom image
CGRect bottomImageRect = CGRectMake(1, totalHeight * foldHeightInPercent, 50, totalHeight * (1.0f - foldHeightInPercent));
CGFloat yPos = image.size.height * foldHeightInPercent * scale;
CGRect bottomCropRect = CGRectMake(0, yPos, image.size.width * scale, image.size.height * (1.0f - foldHeightInPercent) * scale);
CGImageRef bottomImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, bottomCropRect);
UIImageView *bottomImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bottomImageRect];
[bottomImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:bottomImageRef]];
CGImageRelease(bottomImageRef);  

CGFloat skewAngle = 20.0f;
CGFloat skew = tan(skewAngle * M_PI / 180.f);
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, skew, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
bottomImageView.transform = t;
[self.view addSubview:bottomImageView];
```